# Attributes within Method Body

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes

I know that `attributes` *are not supported inside the method body* but i wanted to know maybe someone has work around this. What i am interested in is a technique that allows you to enter `custom Attribute` inside the method body and onto an two things.

1. Class Intensiation (Creating Objects `Foo foo = new Foo()`)
2. When that object calls specific function (`foo.bar()`)

later on I plan to use the `metadata` of the entered `attributes` using `reflection`. I came along a group of people  that actually calims that they have `extented c#` to do so but because of no downloadable I am unable to verify it.

Here is the link to their research paper
[Freely Annotating c#](http://www.jot.fm/issues/issue_2005_12/article2.pdf)
Please advise me the solution

**UPDATE**

further with reflection I already know the name of class Foo and its method bar.
what the purpose of this is to know that foo called bar() in some method.

for Example

```
   static void Main()
       {
           [p1inst]  
           ConcretePrototype1 p1 = new ConcretePrototype1("I");

           [p1call]  
           ConcretePrototype1 c1 = (ConcretePrototype1)p1.Clone();
           Console.WriteLine("Cloned: {0}", c1.Id);

           // Wait for user 
           Console.Read();
       }
```

above is example that illustrate the outcome. At present it can not be done because compiler gives error. but the authors of above mentioned research paper have claimed that they have done this to allow attributes inside the method body

**The whole point is to identify that in some method an object of type `FOO` exists and that object has called `bar()` or not**

Comment: What's the problem you're trying to solve?  It seems that whatever it is could be solved more easily by either adding a property to the class or, if you can't modify the class, creating a wrapper class with the property.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Associating metadata with a function does not cause anything to happen when that function gets called. What are you going to do with this metadata using reflection? Whatever you're going to do with attributes *inside* the function body, you could also do with attribute metadata *outside* of the function body, where they belong.

Comment: @TheEvilPenguin I have updated the question. The approach you are saying can we make sure that call to method `bar()` was made ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are on the wrong track. You can't have attributes inside a method. You either didn't read the paper entirely or missed some points.

It speaks of a source-to-source compiler that just translates

```
public void m() {
    Console.WriteLine("Parallelable code sample");
    [Parallel("Begin of a parallel block")] {
        Console.WriteLine("Code exec by the main thread");
        [Process("First process")] { /∗ Computation here ∗/ }
        [Process] { /∗ Computation here ∗/ }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Here is sequential");
}
```

into this C# code:

```
[Parallel("Parallelable code sample", ACSIndex=1)]
[Process("First process", ACSIndex=2)]
[Process(ACSIndex=3)]
public void m() {
    Console.WriteLine("Parallelable code sample");
    Annotation.Begin(1); { // [Parallel]
        Console.WriteLine("Code exec by the main thread");
        Annotation.Begin(2); /∗ [Process("First process")] ∗/ { · · · }
        Annotation.End(2);
        Annotation.Begin(3); /∗ [Process] ∗/ { · · · }
        Annotation.End(3);
    } 
    Annotation.End(1);
}
```

So when the method `Begin(1)` is called on the `Annotation` class, it will just lookup the method attribute with `ASCIndex=1`.

---

To solve your actual problem, you should look into the [StackTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.aspx) class.

**Example:**

```
void Main()
{
    var f = new FooClass();
    f.Foo();
}

class BarClass
{
    public static void Bar()
    {
        var st = new StackTrace();
        var frame = st.GetFrame(1);
        var m = frame.GetMethod();
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("'{0}' called me from '{1}'", m.DeclaringType.Name, m));
    }
}

class FooClass
{
    public void Foo()
    {
        BarClass.Bar();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

> 'FooClass' called me from 'Void Foo()'

Answer (score 0):

you could add a dictionary with as keys the method names to the class...in a method by reflection you can find out the method name and that way lookup the matching value in the dictionary which would contain your attributes.

I think you don't even need to pre-add the method names in the dictionary as keys; you can put them there the first time the function runs.

Comment: point is I already have method names all i want is them to check whether object of type Foo called bar()